# What is FacebookDisplayName used for?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

We are currently changing the name of an app that is using the Facebook SDK for sign-in (and nothing else really), which means that for non-updated users the name of the Facebook app will not match the value of `FacebookDisplayName`.

During my testing I cannot find any impact on the value of `FacebookDisplayName` being incorrect, does anyone know what it is actually used for?

Comment: your question i don't understand whats you want ?

Answer (score 2):

Your facebook app is uniquely defined by the app ID. The `FacebookDisplayName` is just a textual identifier. You can change it at run time, than you can get it like shown in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.6/constants/FBSettings/):

```
defaultDisplayName

//Get the default Facebook Display Name used by the SDK. If not explicitly set, the default will be read from the application's plist.
+ (NSString *) defaultDisplayName;

//Declared In: FBSettings.h
```

Anyway, on older versions of Facebook SDK:

Facebook SDK 3.5 requires that developers set the Facebook app name in the app's .plist under the key FacebookDisplayName. The value of this key must be an exact match to the value of the Display Name field under Settings in the Facebook devapp.

Comment: So for SDKs newer than 3.5 it's not relevant anymore?

Comment: No don't think so, but there is not much documentation around.

Comment: Even with 3.5 and earlier the value never seemed to matter as far as I could tell, even if the docs said that it had to be an exact match. Architecturally it also seems completely crazy to me, since if it is important then you break clients when renaming your app.

Comment: @StefanFisk I don't have experience before 3.5 but if you say so than yes I agree with you