# What is the purpose of setting facebookDisplayName in the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm developing an app that that uses dynamically set appId & facebookDisplayName as per each customer.
According to the documentation facebookDisplayName can't be changed to whatever was set in the App Portal.
Trying not setting anything for facebookDisplayName worked just fine.
My question is, what's the purpose of setting facebookDisplayName and whether it's required?

SDK Used v4.34

Comment: this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678683/what-is-facebookdisplayname-used-for

Comment: @JakeJohnson thanks for referring me to that SO question, I guess I was looking into a more decisive answer. Should I delete my question and post a comment on the other post?

Comment: It was posted in 2015 so I doubt you’ll get much from commenting there. I don’t think there is too much more info since Facebook doesn’t have much documentation around this. It seems it was once required but no longer. It doesn’t seem to serve much of a purpose now.

Comment: @JakeJohnson that makes sense, thanks for the help!